# Passing messages to a Handler java

Tags: java, android

I have a class that implements two `interfaces` : `OnClickListener` and `Runnable`

When the user presses a button I will go in a Switch like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
           pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait",
                "Generating", false);

           Thread t = new Thread(this);
           t.start();
                      break;
                      }
      }
```

This should start my Run-method, which has an else-statement like this:

```
else {
        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
        msg.obj = "1";
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
```

And my handler method:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {
        pd.dismiss();

        if(m.toString().equals("1")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Do a scan first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    }
};
```

The code runs without any exception, but the `Toast` is not showed, it should be! I am sure that people will say that I should use an `AsyncTask` for this, but thats **not** the answer that I am looking for.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to retrive the object inside the message:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {
        pd.dismiss();
        String message = (String)m.object;
        if(message.equals("1")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Do a scan first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    }
};
```